# Case analysis with REGEX

Tags: regex, if-statement, case, pcre

I have some data like

```
small_animal/Mouse
BigAnimal:Elephant
Not an animal.
```

What I want to get is:

```
Mouse
Elephant
Not an animal.
```

Thus, I need a regular expression that searches for `/` or `:` as follows: If one of these is found, take the text behind that character. If neither `/` nor `:` exists, take the whole string.

I tried a lot. For example this will work for mouse and elephant, but not for the third line:

```
(?<=:)[^:]*|(?<=/)[^/]*
```

And this will always give the full string ...

```
(?<=:)[^:]*|(?<=/)[^/]*|^.*$
```

My head is burning^^ Maybe, somebody can help? :) Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

@[The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) offered a nice solution for single characters. But what if I want to search for strings like

```
animal::Dog
Another123Cat
Not an animal.
```

How can I split on `::` or `123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
^(?:[^:/]*[:/])?\K.+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^:/]*[:/])?` Optionally match any char except `:` or `/` till matching either `:` or `/`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MTlP8U/1)

If you don't want to cross a newline, you can extend the character class with `[^:/\r\n]*`

Another option could be using an alternation

```
^[^:/]*[:/]\K.+|.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7V6Zqh/1)

Or perhaps making use of a SKIP FAIL approach by matching what you want to omit

```
^[^:/]*[:/](*SKIP)(*F)|.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EAQ74d/1)

---

If you want to use multiple characters, you might also use

```
^(?:(?:(?!123|::|[:/]).)*+(?:123|::|[:/]))?\K.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/naJPE0/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working! :) But I have a follow-up question, please see my edit. Maybe you can help here too with your regex skills?

Comment: @Max16hr Like this? `^(?:(?:(?!::|123|[:/]).)*(?:::|123|[:/]))?\K.+` https://regex101.com/r/MZl40C/1